# How to positively say "one bad apple ruins every other good apple"?

Tags: idiom-requests

There is an unhappy colleague in our company and I want to talk about this issue in my next meeting. I want to mean "A bad apple ruins good apples" but this sounds so negative. I want to model it positively. How do I do it?

Comment: Is the positive outcome the removal of the "bad apple" or is it making the "unhappy colleague" a happier one?

Comment: Making "unhappy colleague" a happier one.

Comment: Re-read your title and then correct the English. However, as regards your question, Don't.  If you gild a turd, it is still a turd.

Comment: @David puts it quite eloquently. I'd go further and suggest that you shouldn't ought to want to denegativise the way you express matters, if you make it sound too positive your colleagues may not recognise that you are raising a problem in need of a solution. But any more is well off topic for ELU.

Comment: I suggest posting on [SE The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). If you want to be positive, discuss what can be good for the *employee* and not what is bad for *you*. Appeal to *their* self-interest.

Comment: Like this: One bad apple spoils the whole barrel.

Comment: What country does the idiom need to be understood in? Would an American-English-only reference do?

Comment: You may say :"If professional fulfillment is contagious, wither at work instills negativity.

Comment: FYI, the aphorism you're referring to is usually worded as "one bad apple ruins the whole bunch".

Comment: It's still not clear how you intend to make this a positive. You could use less harsh words, but it's hard to make a positive outcome from unhappiness.

Comment: However you word it, it isn't going to fix someone being "unhappy". You should also be careful about what is considered appropriate in the workplace.

Answer (score 1):

> "No man left behind."

This is an expression from the military. It means, we have a policy of not leaving anyone to suffer, even if it takes significant effort from the group. This is a positive way of saying you want to improve your coworker's performance, implying it's for his/her benefit.

"No man left behind" was adapted to the bill No Child Left Behind in the Bush administration in the U.S. I think if you adapted it to "No employee left behind" it would also work -- Americans, at least, should recognize it.

Comment: This is waaaay off. :)

Comment: It's an entirely different context. "No child left behind" might be closer (about education), but still isn't relevant to the workplace. The question is about the employee's *attitude*, not about being rescued, nor about their ability.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> Sadness may be contagious but happiness is too.

This would state the danger and your concern, but also your hope to address the issue in a positive way.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "bad apple" *itself* often has that meaning. [MW defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bad%20apple)

> 1. someone who creates problems or causes trouble for others
> 2. *often, specifically:* a member of a group whose behavior reflects poorly on or negatively affects or influences the remainder of the group

[TfD defines it as:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bad+apple)

> A person whose own words or actions negatively impacts an entire group of people. Taken from the proverb "a bad apple spoils the bunch."

Answer (score 0):

You could talk about happiness being contagious and how moods can spread. But I don’t see how you can avoid using negative sounding words if you actually want to be specific about what’s happening.
“Bad apple “ is a little judgemental though. It implies the person is bad whereas they are only bad in the context of short term morale. They might actually be “the canary in the coal mine “ highlighting problems that need to be addressed. There’s also the phrase (and a book) called  “a complaint is a gift” about using negative customer feedback to improve business performance.